# CkEditor Template Changes won't take effect

Tags: ckeditor

I downloaded ckeditor, unpacked, installed and all that stuff. It is working fine but I CANNOT change templates in /plugins/templates/templates/default.js. I even deleted them, not working.

Is this how I change templates? (I am desperate here)

PLease HELP!

Comment: Did you cleared browser's cache?

Comment: I cleaned and it worked) thank you) @oleq :)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the docs
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-templates_files

```
config.templates = 'my_templates';
config.templates_files = [
    '/editor_templates/site_default.js',
    'http://www.example.com/user_templates.js
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the browser cache definitely worked.

Go to ***/vendors/ckeditor/plugins/templates/templates/default.js***

Make certain to place every HTML tag and any text between two commas, along with a plus-sign at the end of the ending-commas.

**FYI -** The plus-sign should **NOT** come after the **VERY LAST** HTML tag.

=========================

**EXAMPLE:**

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/templates/templates/default.js

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

How to create your own Custom HTML Template within CKEditor.

I successfully created my own custom-style template, with its own graphical areas within CKEditor.

=========================

Within the CKEditor folder open up the Default JS file found at...

/ckeditor/plugins/templates/templates/default.js

=========================

Make certain to place every HTML tag and every line of text between two (2) commas ,  along with a plus-sign at the end of each of the ending-commas.

FYI - The plus-sign should NOT come after the VERY LAST HTML tag.

=========================

CODE EXAMPLE:

```
                    '<span style="font-size:18px">'+
                    '<strong>'+
                    '<span style="color:#003366">'+
                    '<span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">'+
                    'Here is some sample text'+
                    '</span>'+
                    '</span>'+
                    '</strong>'+
                    '</span>'
```

========================

ONLINE EXAMPLE:

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/templates/templates/default.js

=========================

If you do not see any changes from within the front-end  WYSIWYG for CKEditor , try clearing your browser's cache.

Comment: Please edit your old answer. There's no need to post a second time.